Continue to get a message that my 2.4 ghz network is not available and I need access to it?
So I have approx 30+ devices that can only connect to 2.4ghz bands.  Keeping in mind that most of the former (only 2.4) are light switches, outlets and light bulbs, they are dormant most times (I would assume). However I am getting consistent connectivity issues from this router since I started setting up the smart devices. I am working with a new AT&T Router WiFi Router.
The AT&T installer suggested I “extend” my network but I don’t think that will fix my problem. Any suggestions?
Would a mesh network do better? (Such as Google WiFi or Amplifi Alien)?  My understanding is an extender - extends range, but doesn’t allow for more devices???   So many home automation devices will only work with 2.4ghz

Using a WiFi Extender would indeed likely solve your problem if and only if the reason the devices are disconnecting from the network is due to a signal problem. Is that the case? As you and only you have access to the network and these devices you are the only one that can determine the individual signal strength of each device.

That's a lot of devices. Possibly more than an el-cheapo Wi-Fi router could handle. Please describe your connectivity issues in greater detail, with actual error messages and whatnot.

Your IoT devices are not dormant most times. They are always active to check the server if there is a new message. Like every x seconds. Otherwise pressing a button would not make them turn on or off.
